# When does $\kappa^{<\lambda}=\kappa^\lambda$?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Can cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ with $$\bigcup_{\delta<\lambda}\kappa^\delta=\kappa^\lambda$$
be characterized? Or at least a sufficient condition for this equality be given.
I thing that regularity of both of them is not sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One necessary condition is that the values $\kappa^\delta$ for $\delta<\lambda$ must stabilize.  That is, there must exist some $\delta<\lambda$ such that for all $\delta'$ with $\delta\leq\delta'<\lambda$, $\kappa^{\delta'}=\kappa^\delta$.  Indeed, suppose no such $\delta$ exists (note that this in particular implies $\lambda$ is a limit cardinal).  Then we can pick a cofinal sequence $(\delta_\alpha)$ of the cardinals below $\lambda$ such that $\kappa^{\delta_{\alpha}}<\kappa^{\delta_{\alpha+1}}$ for each $\alpha$.  We then have $$\kappa^{<\lambda}=\sum_\alpha \kappa^{\delta_{\alpha}}$$ and $$\kappa^\lambda=\kappa^{\sum_{\alpha}\delta_{\alpha+1}}=\prod_\alpha \kappa^{\delta_{\alpha+1}}$$ and so $\kappa^{<\lambda}<\kappa^\lambda$ by König's theorem.

Now assuming that $\lambda$ is a limit cardinal and the values of $\kappa^{\delta}$ for $\delta<\lambda$ do stabilize (say, with stable value $\theta$), we have $$\kappa^{<\lambda}=\theta\cdot\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)$$ and $$\kappa^{\lambda}=\theta^{\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)}.$$  Note though that clearly $\kappa^{<\lambda}\geq\lambda\geq\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)$ as long as $\kappa>1$ (and the cases $\kappa\leq 1$ are trivial), so $\kappa^{<\lambda}=\theta$.  If $\lambda$ is singular, then $\operatorname{cf}(\lambda)<\lambda$ so $\theta=\kappa^\delta$ for some $\delta\geq \operatorname{cf}(\lambda)$ and so $\kappa^\lambda=\theta$.  So, when $\lambda$ is singular, $\kappa^{<\lambda}=\kappa^{\lambda}$ iff the values of $\kappa^\delta$ for $\delta<\lambda$ stabilize.

Comment: How can I technically see that "this in particular implies $\lambda$ is a limit cardinal" ?

Comment: If $\lambda$ is a successor then you can take $\delta$ to be its predecessor.

Comment: Right, and how have you derived $\kappa^\lambda=\theta$ from $\theta=\kappa^\delta$ for some $\delta\geq \text{cf}(\lambda)$ ?

Comment: Namely, where have you used $\text{cf}(\lambda)<\lambda$ ?

Comment: $\kappa^\lambda=\theta^{cf(\lambda)}=(\kappa^\delta)^{cf(\lambda)}=\kappa^\delta=\theta$ since $\delta\geq cf(\lambda)$.